# Calling a script with ssh having background command

Tags: ssh

I try to run a script directly having background command, the command is run in background. But when I try to call the same script through ssh from a remote machine the command is not run. Could anyone suggest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the script or at least the relevant parts of it. Indicate which command inside the script is having trouble, and include the ssh command that you're running to invoke the script remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
sshpass -p '$password' ssh user@ip 'sh /path/to/script &'
```

Comment: For example I have included below lines in test.sh and if I execute ./test.sh, and check for process with "ps -ef|grep test2", process will be running.

#! /bin/bash
nohup /path/to/test2 &


But if I call the samescript as below, process is not triggered, "ps -ef|grep test2" gives empty result in the remote host ip.

ssh user@ip "./test.sh"

Comment: Did you get any error when executing the script on the remote server?

Comment: No error is recorded. I want to know if wild card & (which is used to run in background) is working properly when I call the script through ssh from a remote server.